# Issue with querying pouchdb using sqlite-storage plugin

Tags: sqlite, pouchdb

I am using [SQLite adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for pouchdb recently, and I have issue with querying the database. Seems that "key" option for the query function does not work(returns null), and even using "startkey" excludes the startkey itself.
Here is the JavaScript code :

```
var keyShipment= 'aec0ba08-debd-40b1-a023-d75cc360c3af,shipment';
_localdb.query(_v_getByFromRefDocAndType,
                {
                    key: keyShipment,
                    include_docs: true
                });
```

Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?